# Displaying number as a decimal while typing on TextFormField. How to do it with onChanged method?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

For example, when I'm typing 10000 textfield should looks like 10.000 . Is there a way to do that with onChanged? Because when I try with onSubmitted it works.

Comment: you can either use https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter
or make a custom one yourself using TextEditingController and attach it to the TextFormField controller.

Comment: Alright, I will try. Thanks